# Asp Core Multiple Entity Relationships

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on modeling a Contact Info Structure and haven't quite figured out how the relationships should be coded with EF Core. I am fairly new to using EF for data access layer.

I want to have a contact model which can contain Website, Phonenumbers, Emails, or Social Info. Then the contact info will be added to several different models. Any suggestions would be helpful, I am not sure how code this One to many with many table relationship or if it is even possible using EF.

Models so far

```
 public class Contact
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 ContactType { get; set; } //Enum for Website, Phonenumbers, Emails, or Social
    public String RecId { get; set; } //FK to multiple Models
    public String RecType { get; set; }//Value for which model the RecID is for
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}

 public class ContactInfo
{
    public virtual IList<Contact> Website { get; set; } 
    public virtual IList<Contact> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Contact> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Contact> Socials { get; set; }
}
//Example of models to use the contact model
public class Company
{
  ....
  pubic ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set;}
 }
public class Client
{
  ....
  pubic ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set;}
 }
```

Comment: What I understand you want to create one to many relationship with "Company : Contact" and "Client : Contact" tables. Is that right? Then you need to remove ContactInfo table because it is already in one to many relationship itself. Let me know I can give you code sample for that.

Comment: That is correct, that would be awesome.

Comment: This would be very easy to map using owned entity types which are coming in EF Core 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you could use following code sample, but it is not exactly what you are trying to achieve. This may give you some understanding what you need to do with EF.

```
public class Contact
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public ContactType ContactType { get; set; } //Enum for Website, Phonenumbers, Emails, or Social
        public String RecId { get; set; } //FK to multiple Models (This can't be the FK to multiple table as it should be FK for one table so that FK for Company would be CompanyId, FK for the Client should ClientId)
        public String RecType { get; set; }//Value for which model the RecID is for (This need to rethink as it may not needed.)
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }

        // One to Many Relationship

        public string CompanyId? { get; set; }
        public string ClientId? { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        // Other properties

        // One to Many Relationship
        public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        // Other properties

        // One to Many Relationship
        public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }


    /* Db context */

    public class YourDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasKey(t => t.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Contacts).WithOne(c => c.Company).HasForeignKey(k => k.CompanyId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(t => t.Contacts).WithOne(c =>c.Client).HasForeignKey(k => k.ClientId);

        }
    }

    /* Db context - Endd */


    public enum ContactType
    {
        Website,
        PhoneNumbers,
        Emails,
        Social
    }
```

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: In the database, contact will have a CompanyId and ClientId column. For a company contact, ClientId will be 0 and for a client contact, CompanyId will be 0, correct?

Comment: Make those FK's nullable. I have amended answer with "?". So, it will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from DSR, this is the solution I have (untested).

```
public class Company
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContactPhone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactEmail> ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactWebsite> ContactWebsite { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactSocial> ContactSocial { get; set; }

}
public class Client
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContactPhone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactEmail> ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactWebsite> ContactWebsite { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactSocial> ContactSocial { get; set; }
}
 public class ContactWebsite
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Url { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
public class ContactPhone
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
public class ContactEmail
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
public class ContactSocial
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Site { get; set; }
    public String Handle { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```